Inconsistent results with SetPrecision in Manipulate
Here's as simple an example as I can construct to represent the issue.
The user provides 3 values: var1, var2, var3.
I use Symbol here because, in the general case, the user can change the number of variables.
I use precision of 20 here, but in the general case can require higher precision.
The Manipulate collect the values of the 3 variables. If the values do not satisfy the condition that
SetPrecision[var1, precision] + SetPrecision[var2, precision] - SetPrecision[var3,precision] >= 0,

it should show "Condition violated".
Otherwise, it captures those values in rules
output = {var[1] -> SetPrecision[var1, precision], var[2] -> SetPrecision[var2, precision], var[3] -> SetPrecision[var3, precision]}

and displays the result
var[1]+var[2]-var[3]>=0/.output

How is it possible that it displays "False" when var3 is set to the upper limit? Aren't the two tests identical?
With[{vars = Table[With[{i=i}, Symbol[ToString[Row[{"var",i}]]]],{i, 1, 3}],
      precision = 20},
     DynamicModule[{},
           Manipulate@@Join[{(* The output *)
                             If[(* If the values satisfy var[1]+var[2]-var[3] >= 0, ...*)
                                SetPrecision[vars[[1]], precision]+SetPrecision[vars[[2]],precision]-SetPrecision[vars[[3]], precision]>=0,
                                output = Table[With[{i=i}, Rule[var[i],SetPrecision[vars[[i]], precision]]], {i, 1, 3}]; (*... set the values *)
                                var[1]+var[2]-var[3]>=0/.output, (* And test the condition: var[1]+var[2]-var[3] >= 0 *)
                               "Condition violated"]}, (* Otherwise, report the condition is violated *)
                             (* The controls *)
                             Table[With[{i = i},                                         (* Build the condition into the controls *)
                                        {{vars[[i]], 1/100, Row[{"var[", i,"]"}]}, 1/1000, If[i==3, SetPrecision[vars[[1]],precision]+SetPrecision[vars[[2]],precision], 1], Appearance->"Labeled"}], {i, 1, 3}]]]]


This seems related to SetPrecision with Manipulate using variable number of controls

Why you call SetPresition so many times? SetPrecision[var1 + var2 - var3, precision] >= 0 is not good for you?

A.Kato, thanks for your attention. I use SetPrecision on each term to ensure the condition is the same when testing and using the three variables. The rules in output capture their values and I want to ensure that the values used in subsequent computations satisfy the condition var1+ var2 - var3 >= 0.
